# Android-EditText in expandableListView giving trouble with Radiogroup

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have one `EditText`, two `RadioButton`s (for approval/deny) and a submit `Button` in an `ExpandableListView`.

When I type something in the `EditText`, the selection-id of `RadioGroup` gives -1    when I click Submit, but if i don't type anything, it works pretty fine.

But even then I'm able to log the received `EditText` and the `RadioGroup` is not working.

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

@Override public void onClick(View convertView) { 
    if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() ==2131034203){ f=1000; flag=Integer.toString(f); 
    Log.w("commnt",comm); 
        Log.w("time",formattedDate ); 
        Intent i=new Intent(_context.getApplicationContext(),ThankYou.class);
        i.putExtra("flag", flag); i.putExtra("date",formattedDate );    
        _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    else if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() ==2131034204){ 
        Log.w("commnt",comm); 
        f=-999; flag=Integer.toString(f); 
        Log.w("time",formattedDate ); 
        Intent i=new Intent(_context.getApplicationContext(),ThankYou.class); 
        i.putExtra("flag", flag); 
        i.putExtra("date",formattedDate ); 
        _context.startActivity(i); 
        } 

   else { 
             Toast.makeText(_context.getApplicationContext(), "Please check Approve/Deny",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         } 
String id=Integer.toString(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
Log.w("id", id); 
Log.w("commnt",comm); } }); 
return convertView;
```

Comment: 1.addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View convertView) {
             if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() ==2131034203){             
                f=1000;
                flag=Integer.toString(f);
              Log.w("commnt",comm);
                Log.w("time",formattedDate );
                Intent i=new Intent(_context.getApplicationContext(),ThankYou.class);
                i.putExtra("flag", flag);
                i.putExtra("date",formattedDate );
                _context.startActivity(i);
             }

Comment: 2.else if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() ==2131034204){
                 Log.w("commnt",comm);
              f=-999;
              flag=Integer.toString(f);
                Log.w("time",formattedDate );
                Intent i=new Intent(_context.getApplicationContext(),ThankYou.class);
                i.putExtra("flag", flag);
                i.putExtra("date",formattedDate );
                _context.startActivity(i);
             }

Comment: 3.else 
             {
              Toast.makeText(_context.getApplicationContext(), "Please check Approve/Deny",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             
              }
               String id=Integer.toString(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
               Log.w("id", id);
               Log.w("commnt",comm);
            }
        });        
        return convertView;

Comment: @PankajNimgade code is too long to fit in,sry!

Comment: Edit your question with code! don't put it on comment, we can't read it.

Comment: post your code that you add the layouts